# SignalR increasing Disconnect and Keep-Alive timeout increases volume of connections using SSE and volume reconnect requests

Tags: signalr, server-sent-events, signalr.client

We updated our SignalR DisconnectTimeout to 60 seconds from 36 seconds. And our KeepAlive to 20 seconds from 12 seconds.

After this change we noticed an increase in connections using SSE (Server-sent events) and these connections would reconnect every 40 seconds. The reconnect would succeed, but the in the SSE protocol the reconnect returns when the connections has dropped. We are using SignalR version 2.4.1.

Does anyone know why increasing these two configurations for SignalR can cause an increase in reconnects and sessions using SSE?

Our other SignalR global configurations are,

ConnectionTimeout = 110 seconds (Default)

TransportConnectionTimeout = 5 seconds (Default)

DefaultMessageBufferSize = 1000